# CQLSH tab completion and history not working

Tags: cassandra, redhat

I installed Cassandra 5.0.4 using tarball on RHEL 7.2; cqlsh tab completion and history is not working even though I have set "ui" properties in cqlshrc. In addition, I installed setuptools and readline.

Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: have you set  the completekey in ui ?

Comment: it turns out to be python package issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue was related python package; it worked after recompiling the packages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pyreadline.

This package is not included in the minimum set of delivery.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below option which will fix this issue

1. yum install patch
2. yun install readline-devel
3. easy_install readline